# I'm using SOLR 6.1.0 and would like to understand how to extract a particular portion of a document to show as result

Tags: solr, extract

I'm using SOLR 6.1.0 and would like to understand how to extract a particular portion of a document (Word and PDF) to show as result.

Answer (score 1):

`Highlighting` in `Solr` allows fragments of documents that match the user's query to be included with the query response. The fragments are included in a special section of the response (the highlighting section), and the client uses the formatting clues also included to determine how to present the snippets to users.

For more info please check [Highlighting in solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting)